# How to not match/capture characters needed to target something? Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

Let's assume regexp

`/www\.([^\.]+)/ig`

Here string like `www.test.com` with substition to `google` will result in `google.com` instead of `www.google.com` because we captured `www.` as well.

`www.` was needed to target the url but I don't wanna actually capture it. I needed this characters to track down my string but I don't want them to be matched. How to do this thing?

Without grouping, but by just matching and substituting match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex

```
(www\.)([^\.]+)
```

and replace it with the first group + google i.e
    www.google

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/qcVSPQ/1).

To do this without grouping you can use a positive lookbehind

```
(?<=www\.)([^\.]+)
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/qcVSPQ/2)

Comment: But how to do this without grouping, just matching,

Comment: added to the answer

Comment: Is there other way to do this?

Comment: Sorry but I'm aware of only these 2 ways